# NGINX proxy caching - cache buster variable in querystring - possible to ignore?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, querystring

We have the following url we would like to proxy cache:

```
file.php?parameter=one&paramater2=two&r=EPOCHTIMESTAMP
```

Query string parameter "parameter" varies between requests. So does "paramater2".

Query stringing parameter r is a timestamp we use to make sure the client doesn't serve cached (on the client side) content. Aka "cache buster". Yes we also use all the appropriate don't cache h headers.

Now, we would like to proxy cache via nginx some of these requests. Is it possible to instruct nginx to ignore the r querystring param but use all the others when setting a cache key for the entry? If we can't ignore param r then the nginx proxy cache will be useless as each cache key will be unique.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have found a solution to this question.

The correct method of doing this is to construct a cache key by using nginx `$arg_...` variables. `$arg_...` will contain query string parameters. So in the above example we would use `$arg_parameter` and `$arg_parameter2` within the cache key.

The result in the `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
http {
  ...
    server {
      location / {
         ...
         proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$arg_parameter$arg_parameter2;
      }
    }
  ...
}
```

Note that querystring parameter containing an hyphen (dash), such as `data-*` parameters, do not work with the `$arg_paramName` syntax. A workaround using Lua can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351994/918244).